# xtext generated method are wrong in the generator

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf, xtend

Good morning, 
i'm new in xtext. I wrote a grammar for my dsl and  in the genrator a method generated in the model give we wrong result:
 the grammar snipped that is wrong is:
Feature:

```
'Feature' name=ID '{'
    'verb' verb= [Activity]
    'objects' '('(classes+=[Class] (','classes+=[Class])*)?')'
    'common' '('(common+=[Feature] (','common+=[Feature])*)?')'     
    'optional' '('(optional+=[Feature] (','optional+=[Feature])*)?')'
    'variabilities' '(' (variabilities+=[FeatureVariability] (','variabilities+=FeatureVariability])*)?')'  
    'generalization' '('(generalization+=[Feature] (','generalization+=Feature])*)?')'      
 '}';
```

an then have model with the following Features:

Feature f2{

```
         verb act1
         objects (C4, C3)
         common()
         optional(f32, f31)
         variabilities()    
         generalization()
        }
```

Feature f3{

```
         verb act1
         objects (C1, C2, C3)
         common()
         optional(f31, f32)
         variabilities()    
         generalization()
    } 

Feature f31{


         verb act2
         objects (C3)
         common()
         optional()
         variabilities()    
         generalization()
    }


Feature f32{
         verb act1
         objects (C1, C2, C3)
         common()
         optional()
         variabilities()    
         generalization()
    }
```

Feature f4{

```
         verb act1
         objects (C1, C2, C3)
         common()
         optional(f32, f31)
         variabilities()    
         generalization()
    }
```

Feature f1{

```
         verb act1
         objects (C1, C4)
         common(f2)
         optional(f31)
         variabilities()          
         generalization()}
```

when i display the features names, common's size common's contains , optional

size optionnal size, optionnal contain, i have the following results:

feature name:f2, size of common:2 common featuresf32,f31

feature name:f2, size of optional:2 optional featuresf32,f31

feature name:f3, size of common:2 common featuresf31,f32

feature name:f3, size of optional:2 optional featuresf31,f32

feature name:f31, size of common:0 common features

feature name:f31, size of optional:0 optional features

feature name:f32, size of common:0 common features

feature name:f32, size of optional:0 optional features

feature name:f4, size of common:2 common featuresf32,f31

feature name:f4, size of optional:2 optional featuresf32,f31

feature name:f1, size of common:2 common featuresf2,f31

feature name:f1, size of optional:2 optional featuresf2,f31

but when i use Junit to test, everithing is ok.
thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please state what you do in generator and how unit test is done and what the actual error is

Comment: the actual error is that in the generator when I get the field "common" of feature, the size is not always what it is supposed to be. for example in the post, for the feature f1 common is (f2) so, the size is 1 but when i display f1.common.size() it display 2 and when i display the features i have f2 and f31 instead of f2

Comment: Junit test is to ensure that all the field of the feature contains what expected

Comment: In the generator i use each feature to in the fields (common, optional, genralization) to infer another concept of the language. if discover the mistake when for that particular "f1" three concept where generated one corresponding to f2 and two for f31. it then came to my mind to display the contain of those field. i found that "common" was having f2 and f31 as features and "optional" was having f31

Comment: sorry without beeing able to actually reproduce this. no changes. btw: ususal way to do m2m is not done in generator but in iderivedstatecomputer

Comment: thank you i did not know about IderivedStateComputer, but I think i need to use the generator since the concepts derived are put in a different file and will be used in other programs using import mechanisms

Comment: as i said: would need something reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure if you work with your feature lists in the validator and generator, that you dont accientially do a model2model transformation e.g.

`feature.common + feature.optional`